# Replace all but the first 1 in an array with 0

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to replace all of the duplicate 1 with 0. As an example:

```
[[0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,0,1]]
```

Should become:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0]]
```

I found a similar problem, however the solution does not seem to work [numpy: setting duplicate values in a row to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909364/numpy-setting-duplicate-values-in-a-row-to-0)

Comment: Do you want to use NumPy, or only Python's standard library?

Comment: Forgot to mention, yes i use numpy, and numpy arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume array contains only zeros and ones, you can find the max value per row using `numpy.argmax` and then use [advanced indexing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing.htm) to reassign the values on the index to a zeros array.

```
arr = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,0,1]])

res = np.zeros_like(arr)
idx = (np.arange(len(res)), np.argmax(arr, axis=1))
res[idx] = arr[idx]

res
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Try looping through each row of the grid

In each row, find all the `1`s. In particular you want their indices (positions within the row). You can do this with a list comprehension and `enumerate`, which automatically gives an index for each element.

Then, still within that row, go through every `1` except for the first, and set it to zero.

```
grid = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]

for row in grid:
    ones = [i for i, element in enumerate(row) if element==1]
    for i in ones[1:]:
        row[i] = 0

print(grid)
```

Gives: [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: I think i will use the solution the other person gave because it looks like it would be much faster

Comment: Agreed - if it is a much larger array than you showed. The method I show is aimed at ease of understanding and modifying, rather than fast performance on a giant dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumsum:

```
(arr.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) == 1) * 1
```

this will create a cummulative sum, by then checking if a value is 1 you can find the first 1s